# How can I upload database data to Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, bioinformatics

Using an pan-genome building tool I've ended with a database in an unfamiliar format to me which in theory should be explorable by the Neo4j browser.
Nevertheless I can't seem to find any way to achieve so and any mention on how to do it in any bibliography besides the instructions of the manual provided by the author of said tool.

I've tried to do this using Neo4j community edition server (v. 3.5.3) with the example file same as the instructions suggest but it just doesn't seem to detect the database showing only the default one.

The mentioned part of the tutorial can be found here: https://www.bioinformatics.nl/pangenomics/manual/tutorial_part3/

Answer (score 0):

So, copy the database content to the neo4j data folder. Once you have that, open the neo4j.conf file and set the following configuration:

```
dbms.default_database=chloroplast_DB
```

I am not exactly sure that is the database name, use the same name as is the database folder and then start the database.